# Send email after registration using controller or route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, email

I want to send an email to the admin not the user that a new user is requested to be registered. I tried this in controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Mail;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Jrean\UserVerification\Traits\VerifiesUsers;
use Jrean\UserVerification\Facades\UserVerification;


 class RegisterController extends Controller
 {

  use RegistersUsers;


  protected $redirectTo = '/regmessage';



 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->middleware('guest');
 }

 /**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
 protected function validator(array $data)
 {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'usertype' => 'required',
    ]);
 }

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
  protected function create(array $data)
  {
    //dd($data);
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],
        'status' => 0,
    ]);
    $user = array('name' => 'Admin');

    Mail::send('emails.reminder', $user, function ($m) {


        $m->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Confirm email');
    });
  }

  /*public function sendEmailReminder(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user],
    function ($m) use($user) {


        $m->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Confirm email');
       });
    }*/

 }
```

and i also tried this in route.php..after doing this in route the email is sending but the registration form values is not inserting into database.what i need to do here?

```
Route::post('/register',function() 
{
$data = array('name' => 'Admin');

Mail::send('emailMessage', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
    ->subject('Confirm email');
});

return view('regmessage');
});
```

Comment: Any specific errors returned from your database class?

Comment: no error is showing....if i write that code in route email is coming but form values not inserting into db...and if i write in controller then nothing happens just page reloaded

Comment: I think you should use mail code before return in controller. try once.

Comment: any example on how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your controller code need to update like:

```
protected function create(array $data)
 {
   //dd($data);
   $user = User::create([
       'name' => $data['name'],
       'email' => $data['email'],
       'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],
       'status' => 0,
   ]);
   $use = array('name' => 'Admin');

   Mail::send('emails.reminder', $use, function ($m) {

       $m->from('your from email address')
       $m->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
       $m->subject('Confirm email');
   });
  return $user;
 }
```

**UPDATE**
Make change like: 
`Mail::send('emails.reminder', $use, function ($m) use($data){...}` and use `$data['email']`.

Hope this work for you!

Comment: nope! just page reloaded no email is sent no data is inserted into db. i tried after clearing the cache and restarting the php artisan

Comment: Please provide your `User model` code and what see what does `dd($data)` for you?

Comment: your code just needed to edit two lines and that is working now. thnx

Comment: @incorporeal: And what is it?

Comment: see i already updated ... returning the $user in last and setting the create function in $user fucntion

Comment: @incorporeal: Great, Thanks...And glad to help..!

Comment: can you say how can i use the email address as sender that i am taking in create function?? @Addweb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: @incorporeal: See *UPDATE*

Comment: i tried like this but not working......     `Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) use ($data) {

     $m->from($data['email'])
       ->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
       ->subject('Confirm email');
        });
     
     return $user;
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132983/discussion-between-incorporeal-and-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd).

Comment: @incorporeal: Create a new question for same, may this help to both.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is opinionated, I find that when you want to react to a model's event (in this case, a user creation), it's best to hook into capture that event in the Model's boot method. Furthermore, do not send emails in a way that it blocks the response in the server. Job's handle this functionality much better.

First, create the job to handle this:

```
php artisan make:job SendAdminEmailOnUserCreation
```

Open that new job, then locate the handle function.

```
public function handle(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mail)
{
    $mail->send('emails.reminder', ['name' => 'Admin'], function ($message) {
        $message->from('me@my-domain.com')
            ->to('admin@my-domain.com')
            ->subject('A new user has registered');
    });
}
```

Next, make sure that your job implements the `ShouldQueue` factory:

```
class SendAdminEmailOnUserCreation implements ShouldQueue {
```

Then in your `App\User` model:

```
public static function boot () 
{
    parent::boot();

    User::created(function(){
        dispatch(new SendAdminEmailOnUserCreation());
    });
}
```

Finally, make sure that your queue is running in order to correctly handle this job:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

**Note**

In your question you're using `emails.reminder`, which if that's anything like `emails.auth.reminder` it requires the `$token` variable. Otherwise, if you've modified this, make sure the only variable it is looking for is `$name` otherwise you'll receive an error.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

after editing my create function in controller i got the result...my value is inserting into db and an email is sending to the amin that a user is requested to be registered.here's my code

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    //dd($data);

    $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],
        'status' => 0,
    ]);
    $use = array('name' => 'Admin');

 Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) {

 $m->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
   ->subject('Confirm email');
    });
 return $user;
}
```

thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Exactly that is i was telling you in last comment. Happy that your code is working now. :)

Comment: can yo say how can i use the email as sender which i am taking is create function. @jyotimishra

Comment: Please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) {
 $m->to('To email id')
   ->subject('Confirm email');
 $m->from('From email id');   
    });
```

Comment: 'to email id' is dynamic. not fixed. taking input from users

Comment: 'email' => $data['email'], Is it to email? you are sending mail after registration.

Comment: no it is the email i want to set as 'from email id'

Comment: can you show your latest controller code in which you are taking input from users.

Comment: this is `$use = array('name' => 'Admin', 'userEmail' => $data['email']);
        //$models->emailw = Auth::user()->email;

     Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) use ($use){

        $m->from($use['userEmail'])
            ->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
            ->subject('Confirm email');
    });
     return $user;`